# Remove current array element from Redux array

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Here is my reducer

```js
const initialState = {
  pros: [''],
}

export const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTION_ADD_PROS:
      return {
          ...state.pros,
          pros: [...state.pros,  action.payload]
        }

    case ACTION_CHANGE_PROS:
      return update(state, { 
        pros: { 
          [action.index]: {
            $set: action.payload
          }}
      });

    case ACTION_REMOVE_PROS:   

   ???


      return x
    default:
  }
  return state;
};
```

Can some one help me how can I remove current item from array?
I have tried many ways but I don't understand what the problem here,
also I have used react-addons-update for update store

Comment: you are removing an item based on `id`? or just the last or first one?

Comment: I'm trying to remove based on index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) would be the most easy and readable solution to remove an item from an array:

```
return {
  pros: state.filter((item, index) => index !== action.index)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this should do the trick ( haven't tested )

you need to create a copy of the array, remove the item, and then assign the new array to the state

```
const initialState = {
pros: [''],
}

export const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case ACTION_ADD_PROS:
    return {
        ...state.pros,
        pros: [...state.pros,  action.payload]
        }

    case ACTION_CHANGE_PROS:
    return update(state, { 
        pros: { 
        [action.index]: {
            $set: action.payload
        }}
    });

    case ACTION_REMOVE_PROS:
    // make a copy of the array
    const newArr = state.pros
    // remove item at index 4
    newArr.splice(newArr.indexOf(action.payload), 1)   

    return update(state, {
           pros: [...newArr]
    })

   //this is the old code that is incorrect
   /* return update(state, { 
        pros: { 
        [action.index]: {
            $set: newArr
        }}
    });/*


    return x
    default:
}
return state;
};
```

for more information about the [array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Remember: NEVER EDIT THE STATE DIRECTLY. the state needs to be immutable

edit: the return method was wrong, please try this one
edit: as from your comment, i corrected the newArr
also now it should remove the "current" value from the array
basically you wan't to edit the copy of the array and then just assign the smaller array

Comment: It's not helped, maybe with ACTION_ADD_PROS something wrong?

Comment: also the action.payload is the current value of INPUT and not array

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `splice`ing, just `slice` the array before the index, after the index, and return the combined array.

It'd keep the original array untouched

```
  [
    ...state.pros.slice(0, action.index),
    ...state.pros.slice(action.index + 1)
  ]
```